# Orientation to grasp object from y axis

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I’m trying to achieve pick and place in gazebo by sending trajectory from moveit.
I noticed in moveit pick and place tutorial that orientation is given as follows:

```
orientation.setRPY(-M_PI / 2, -M_PI / 4, -M_PI / 2)
```

This orientation tries to pick the object from x-axis direction ( considering x axis is forward, y axis is pointing to the left and z axis is upwards.) Below image demonstartes how my robot arm positions itself when given above orienatation

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

I want to grasp the object from y axis side i.e parallel to the yellow axis shown in the image. What can be the orientation of the robot??

I have came till this orientation:

```
orientation.setRPY(-M_PI / 4, -M_PI/2 , -M_PI /4)
```

below is the image representing robot arm with this orientation.
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

if you see then gripper is still inclined and not exactly horizontal.
can anyone tell me what can be orientation to grasp the object from y axis direction??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316594/orientation-to-grasp-object-from-y-axis/) by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2019-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-04**:
Could you please not close questions if you've actually answered them?

Please click the checkmark to the left of the / your answer instead.

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2019-03-04**:
sure. My bad as i didn’t know this process. I’ll follow as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would report what worked for me:

Due to initial rotation of robot around z axis i was not able to approach the object exactly as i wanted.
Below is the orientation which can help you to approach the object in y axis direction if you dont have any initial rotation.

```
orientation.setRPY(-M_PI / 4, -M_PI/2 , -M_PI /4);
```

---

Originally posted by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) with karma: 104 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0